# how to clone instance in CKeditor?

Tags: html, ckeditor

i want to make clone of existing instance of ckeditor. i am really not known how to make it.

i make a textarea who have a class .editor and i want to add a new instance with blank data after clicking on button with same class.

how i can make a clone instance [blank] and append them in after existing intance  ?

any idea how i can add new instance of making clone of existing instance of ckeditor ?

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/manektech/47htysb5/1/

Comment: @MayankDudakiya thanks for the link, you are little bit late :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample shows how you can create new instances as needed: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/ajax.html

Of course, there are other ways; it's a matter of studying your requirements and check what's the best approach.

Comment: This is a broken link now.